# Multimedia-Content

Tags: release-juno, firefox, epiphany, chromium, multimedia

I can not display multimedia content in some browsers (Epiphany + Vivaldi). Firefox + Chromium works fine. I manually copied the Chromium codec into the Vivaldi directory. Unfortunately, did not help. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

For Epiphany, you need to install the gstreamer1.0-libav package.

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

I don't known about Vivaldi, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

to enable the HTML5 proprietary multimedia content you must install support for it.

Execute the following command in the terminal:

```
curl https://launchpadlibrarian.net/414953672/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_73.0.3683.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb | tail -c + 1077 | tar JxC ~ --wildcards \ * libffmpeg.so --xform 's,. * /,. local / lib / vivaldi /,'
```

After that, restart the browser.

To check that support for proprietary HTLM5 multimedia content is enabled correctly, go to the following page:

> https://tekeye.uk/html/html5-video-test-page

Then enjoy your favorite multimedia content, ^^

References:

> https://help.vivaldi.com/article/html5-proprietary-media-on-linux/

**Important Note: If this solves your problem, DO NOT FORGET to mark this post as resolved.**

Cya